# How to load Xmir on my tablet/phone with Ubuntu Touch Saucy

Tags: ubuntu-touch, nexus-7, mir

On my tablet/phone do not run X11 applications with the default Ubuntu Touch Saucy configuration (all my favourite desktop applications like okular, kate, x11vnc, etc...).  As I found [here][How to load Xmir on Ubuntu 13.10 the XMir is required. Unfortunately Ubuntu Touch on phone/tablet do behaves differently and the reply above do not solve this issue.

I am testing the Xmir on Nexus 7 tablet. There is intalled/running unity8 + lightdm + mir and unity-system-compositor + Xorg.

I am still getting message above after system reboot in the /var/log/Xorg.0.log :

```
[    81.542] (II) "glx" will be loaded by default.
[    81.542] (WW) "xmir" is not to be loaded by default. Skipping.
[    81.542] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
```

Answer (score -1):

to run X sessions under Mir, with Mir acting as the system compositor, create the file /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/10-unity-system-compositor.conf to look to look like this:

```
[SeatDefaults]
type=unity
```

then restart ligthdm.
see http://unity.ubuntu.com/mir/using_mir_on_pc.html for more details.